# Babylon js tree shaking typescript and createDynamicTexture is not a function

Tags: typescript, babylonjs

I'm looking to update my codebase to Tree Shaking in Babylon JS.  I've imported babylon core and I'm noticing random missing functions.

As I understand it it seems like I need to import something, but these functions are on the scene or the engine and I've tried just importing the code, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
import * as DynamicTexture from "@babylonjs/core/Engines/Extensions/engine.dynamicTexture";
```

What is the correct way to import these missing functions?

Answer (score 0):

To use this function you will need to import the DynamicTexture from the materials, which will take care of importing the correct engine extension:

```js
import DynamicTexture from '@babylonjs/core/Materials/Textures/dynamicTexture';
```